# Aborting WCF proxy that has non-cached ChannelFactory with CancellationToken causes deadlock

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, task-parallel-library

So here's how it is.

There is a WCF service. I've generated a proxy for it by "Add Service Reference" with task-based operations.

Endpoint address for that service might change for different users. I have no control over this service, vendor just does that this way.

Then I wrap that service into another type and through that type interaction with WCF service occurs.

It all looks like this:

```
//Generated code
public partial class MyServiceClient: System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IMyService>, IMyService
{
   public async Task<ResultDataContractType> GetResultsAsync(ArgsDataContractType args)
   {
      return base.Channel.GetResultsAsync(args); 
   }
}

...
...
...
//end of generated code

public class ClientFactory
{
   public static IMyService CreateClient(string url)
   {
      var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
      var address = new EndpointAddress(url);
      var client = new MyServiceClient(binding, address);
      return client;
   }
}

public class Wrapper()
{
    public async Task<ResultType> GetResultsAsync(string url, ArgsType args, CancelationToke cancelationToken)
    {
        var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient(url);

        try
        {
            cancellationToken.Register(target =>
            {
                var communicationObject = target as ICommunicationObject;
                if (communicationObject != null)
                {
                    communicationObject.Abort();
                }
            }, client);

            ArgsDataContractType requestArgs = MapArgs(args);

            ResultDataContractType result = await client.GetResultsAsync(args);
       }
    }
}


public class Consumer
{
   public async void DoWork()
   {
      var args = new ArgsType 
      {
         ...
      };

      var cts = new CancellationTokenSource()

      var wrapper = new Wrapper();

      Task<ResultType> task = wrapper.GetResultsAsync("http://someaddress.com", args, cts.Token);

      cts.Cancel(); //This is made intentionaly, normaly there is timeout timespan for token source

      await task;

      ... 
      ...
      ...

   }
}
```

`Consumer` is actually the NUnit unit test, but calling the same code from ASP.NET application would also end up in a deadlock. It gets stuck on `await task;`

What I have noticed, that if I would set `MyServiceClient.CacheSetting = CacheSetting.AlwaysOn;` will make that code run without deadlocking.

Also, if I would configure `MyServiceClient` from App.config or Web.config will make code running without deadlocking. But if I would set `MyServiceClient.CacheSetting = CacheSetting.AlwaysOff;` before instantiating `MyServiceClient` this code will deadlock.

Also, configuring awaiter like this:

```
ResultDataContractType result = await client.GetResultsAsync(args).ConfigureAwait(false)
```

Will make code run without deadlocking.

Could you please enlighten me with any idea why's that deadlock doesn't happens when `ChannelFactory` for `MyServiceClient` is cached, and will happen if it is not cached?

Comment: To fix your unit tests, use `async Task` instead of `async void`. Does the deadlock still happen if you use a timeout instead of cancelling directly?

Comment: I've tried `async Task`, it didn't help.
Making it acutaly timeout will not cause deadlock.

Comment: I've been reading your blogs and "Concurrency in C# Cookbook" past few days. Good job and i'm glad to meet you!